# Setting Foreign Key using pgAdmin 3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm totally new to SQL and programming. Downloaded PostgreSQL recently and been playing with pgAdmin3. I have two questions.

Question 1:

Based on the table below, how can I create a foreign key to "Ref - Unit Role_Unit Type" using pgAdmin3? "Ref - Unit ROle_Unit Type" may include one or more values from the table "Drop - Unit Type_Unit Type".

```
CREATE TABLE public."Ref - Unit Role"
(
  "Unit Role" character(20) NOT NULL,
  "RAT Role" character(20),
  "Unit Type" character(20)[],
  CONSTRAINT "Ref - Unit Role_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Unit Role"),
  CONSTRAINT "Ref - Unit Role_RAT Role_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("RAT Role")
      REFERENCES public."Drop - RAT Role" ("RAT Role") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."Ref - Unit Role"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Question 2:
Based on the table below, what I'm trying to do is, after "Unit_Unit Type" are keyed in, by referring to the table "Ref - Unit Role" above, "Unit_Unit Role" will only accept "Ref - Unit Role_Unit Role" where "Ref - Unit Role_Unit Type" = "Unit_Unit Type". Is that possible?

```
CREATE TABLE public."Unit"
(
  "Unit Type" character(20),
  "Unit Chassis" character(30) NOT NULL,
  "Unit Model" character(20) NOT NULL,
  "Unit Weight" integer,
  "Unit Role" character(20),
  "Unit Production Year" daterange[],
  "Unit Manufacturer" character(30)[],
  CONSTRAINT "Unit_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Unit Chassis", "Unit Model"),
  CONSTRAINT "Unit_Unit Chassis_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("Unit Chassis")
      REFERENCES public."Drop - Unit Chassis" ("Unit Chassis") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "Unit_Unit Model_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("Unit Model")
      REFERENCES public."Drop - Unit Model" ("Unit Model") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "Unit_Unit Type_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("Unit Type")
      REFERENCES public."Drop - Unit Type" ("Unit Type") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."Unit"
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE public."Drop - Unit Type"
(
  "Unit Type" character(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Drop - Unit Type_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Unit Type")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."Drop - Unit Type"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Please post it as two questions. And this is not really about pgadmin. This is about running sql queries through any old client.

Comment: Because my second question is related to the first question, that's why I posted it together. If can be done, how do I setup using pgadmin?